# Fill 2d array value in python with another 1d array per column

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have this code :

```
series =[]
list = type.groupby('level').size()
```

that list is equal = `[20,40,40]`

So, I want to have this loop:

```
series[0:3]=list
```

until here, its work but I want to have 2d matrix so I can save that list value for each loop.
matrixb=np.zeros((3,15))

```
for i in range (15):
    matrix[0:3][i]=series[0:3]
```

it does not work,
`could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (15,)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform such an assignment. You'd need to break them up as such:

```
for i in range (15):
    matrix[0][i] = series[0]
    matrix[1][i] = series[1]
    matrix[2][i] = series[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it like this:

```
list = [20, 40, 40]
series = list.copy()
matrix = np.zeros((3,15))

for i in range(15):
    matrix[:,i] = series
```

which gives `matrix`:

```
[[20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20.]
 [40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40.]
 [40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40.]]
```